# How to project fields in mongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have the structure of documents in the collection like this:

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("569190cd24de1e0ce2dfcd62"),
  "title" : "Star Trek II: The Wrath of Khan",
  "year" : 1982,
  "rated" : "PG",
  "released" : ISODate("1982-06-04T04:00:00Z"),
  "runtime" : 113,
  "countries" : [
    "USA"
  ],
  "awards" : {
    "wins" : 2,
    "nominations" : 9,
    "text" : "2 wins & 9 nominations."
  }
}
```

I'm trying to get the contents of specific fields using the projection and adding a couple of additional parameters. I want to take such keys as: `title`, `year`, `rated` and `awards` with the specified values. (and `_id` remove)

I write so `db.movieDetails.find( {}, {title: 1, year: 2013, rated: "PG-13", _id: 0, "awards.wins": 1 }).pretty()` to get the fields with values, but console displays different parameters:

```
{
   "title" : "Star Trek II: The Wrath of Khan",
   "year" : 1982,
   "rated" : "PG",
   "awards" : {
     "wins" : 2,
   }
}
```

I want to have the output like this, for example:

```
{
   "title" : "Star Trek II: The Wrath of Khan",
   "year" : 2013,
   "rated" : "PG-13",
   "awards" : {
     "wins" : 0
   }
}
```

Tell me, please, what needs to be corrected in the query to have only my concrete requirements... I appreciate everyone's help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do something like that

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      title: 1,
      _id: 0,
      year: 2013,
      rated: "PG-13",
      "awards.wins": "0"
    }
  }
])
```

Will give following output

```
[
  {
    "awards": {
      "wins": "0"
    },
    "rated": "PG-13",
    "title": "Star Trek II: The Wrath of Khan",
    "year": 1982
  }
]
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution, but I have error: `db.movieDetails.aggregate([ {$project: { title:1, _id:0, year: 2013, rated: "PG-13", "awards.wins": 0 } } ])
assert: command failed: {
        "ok" : 0,
        "errmsg" : "Bad projection specification, cannot exclude fields other than '_id' in an inclusion projection: { title: 1.0, _id: 0.0, year: 2013.0, rated: \"PG-13\", awards.wins: 0.0 }",
        "code" : 40178,
        "codeName" : "Location40178"
} : aggregate failed`

Comment: @invzbl3 you can check it here https://mongoplayground.net/p/qr0RiU7CgWX

Comment: thank you a lot, solve it! Really what I need. Website and your solution are very helpful :)

Answer (score 2):

Filtering should be done inside first parameter of the find() function and projection should be done inside second parameter of the find function.

Comment: can u give an example, pls?

Comment: db.collection.find({year : 2013},{title: 1, year:1 , rated: 1, _id: 0,awards:1, "awards.wins": 1 })

Comment: as i understand you want to filter by rated and year fields. then you should try this:   db.collection.find({year : 2013,rated:"PG-13"},{title: 1, year:1 , rated: 1, _id: 0,awards:1, "awards.wins": 1 })

Comment: Thanks, Serdar. I understand, how it works. `db.movieDetails.find({year : 2013, rated:"PG-13", "awards.wins": 0},{title: 1, year:1 , rated: 1, _id: 0,awards:1, "awards.wins": 1 }).pretty()`.